# Check for stationarity $X(t) = V * \cos(wt+U)$, V and U are indep. rand. variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Can somebody help me please to figure out how to solve this problem:

Are the following process stationary?

$X(t) = V \cos(wt+U), t\epsilon R^1$

U and V are independent variables,

$U$ ~ $Uniform(-\pi,\pi)$, $E[V] = m_v, Var(V) = D_v$, $w \epsilon R^1$

To check stationariy I need to calculate $E, Var, Cov()$. I've tried to calculate $E[X(t)]$, but I don't understand what I can do with cosine.

$E[X(t)] = E[V*\cos(wt+U)] = E[V] * E[\cos(wt+U)] = m * $ ...

Is it possible to say that $wt+U = 0$, because $U$ has Uniform distribution? But I really not sure. Or I need to take some integral?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't you know some nice formula that can break cos(w*t + U) into factors that only have t or U inside the trigonometric functions?

Comment: You mean: cos(a+b) = cos(a)*cos(b)-sin(a)*sin(b)? Yea, I was thinking about it. But then I'll get E[cos(U)] - what can I do with this?

Comment: Yes, I was referencing that formula ;) Then you should apply the definition of what is the expected value of a function of a random variable. Here is some reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXzEqs5DK8I

Comment: Cool, thank you!:) 
I've calculated E and Var, I get 0 and m_v* D_v, respectively.
If I get something similar for Cov function (by similar I mean without t variable), can I say that the process is stationary?

Comment: I'm not sure of what a stationary process means in this context

Comment: According to the lectures, X(t) is said to be stationary if:
1. EX(t) = m for all t.
2. EX^2(t) < infinity for all t.
3. Cov(s,t) = Cov(s+h,t+h) for all s, t, s+h, t+h.
As I understood, generally it means that E, Var and Cov functions of a stochastic process should be independent of time.

Comment: The idea of StackExchange community is that we help each other with stuff that we already tried to figure out by ourselves. I think you have all the necessary tools for moving forward. If you hit another point where you get stuck, get back, show what you have done and why it isn't working and we will help you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answers:)